# JQuery, possible to add a css attribute to a dialog button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

This is code I've put together so far.

I've found where you can add a class, but I just want to change the colour of the buttons to grey, to make them look more natural, rather than the standard blue.

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divdeps").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Yes",
                    click: function() {
                        // Cancel code here
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "No",
                    click: function() {
                        // Save code here
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ],
```

-- spacer --

```
            close: function() {
                // Close code here (incidentally, same as Cancel code)
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            open: function () {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("boxtitlebg");
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("height", "17px");
                $(".ui-widget-header").css("border", "none");
                $(".ui-widget-content").css("border", "none");

            }
        });
    });
   </script>

<div id="divdeps" style="display: none" title="this title">This is my div</div>

<div onclick="$('#divdeps').dialog('open');">click here</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button').css("border", "none");
```

Comment: How was this relevant to the question about button color?

Comment: $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button').css("color", "red");

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS attributes to any jQuery object:

```
$("<selector>").css("background-color", "#ddd");
```

Just figure out what your selector should be, and this should do it. All of the buttons should have a common class, so that is likely the selector you should use.